Do PCIe bar regions have physical memory allocated in host RAM?
Based on my understanding, during PCIe enumeration, the kernel reads the device PCIe config space and "allocates" some memory regions for the different BARs. I see different BAR regions in the lspci with start offsets and I was wondering if these offsets are offsets in actual physical memory.
Context: I am trying to understand how a user space process tries to mmap this BAR region. When the user process accesses the mmap-ed virtual addresses, do the reads and writes go to the physical memory, which is then routed by PCIe to the device? Or does the any attempt to access this mapped BAR region directly get translated to reads/writes on the device?

It's all about address space:s. The MMIO has it's own. On NUMA machines it's much more complicated. Even on regular end-user desktop CPUs the "physical memory" can be not a single address space. After you get this, you need to understand how MMIO addresses are being mapped to the virtual address space and how cache is involved here. But answering shortly to your title question: no, there is no physical memory allocated for these address regions.
